# How to store game level score in Android?

Tags: android, game-development

Please tell me how to store the level information (like angry birds levels display screen contains `*` or `**` or `***` same as my Android game).

Comment: can't you use SQLite?..and please update your question with more description.

Comment: Use SharedPreference. And yeah... as Frankenstein suggested: Add more detail

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can store them using [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

```
public void saveDataToPreferencesFile(Context ctx, String filename, String...data) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = ctx.getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();     

        for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i += 2) {
            editor.putString(data[i], data[i + 1]); 
        }

        editor.commit();
}
```

Where you can make the following call:

```
saveDataToPreferencesFile(context, "scores", new String [] {"score", "3"});
```

You can then read the value by doing:

```
public String readDataFromPreferencesFile(Context ctx, String filename, String key) {
        SharedPreferences prefs =  ctx.getSharedPreferences(filename, ctx.MODE_PRIVATE);

        return installationSession.getString(key, "0");
    }
```

And make the following call:

```
readDataFromPreferencesFile(context, "scores", "score");
```

This is easier and lighter than using *SQLite* to store them (unless you really need a relational model).